# Remove duplicates from row applying exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, string, duplicates

I try to remove duplicates on rows but I need to have strings with length <= 2 and integer.

I have a sentence like this:

```
AIR OPTIX Air Optix plus HydraGlyde Lenti a Contatto Mensili, 6 Lenti, BC a 6 mm, DIA 14.2 mm, -0.75 Diopt
```

What I need to obtain is:

```
AIR OPTIX plus HydraGlyde Lenti a Contatto Mensili, 6 Lenti, BC a 6 mm, DIA 14.2 mm, -0.75 Diopt
```

What I manage to do with the below function is:

```
AIR OPTIX plus HydraGlyde Lenti Contatto Mensili, 6 Lenti, BC mm, DIA 14.2 -0.75 Diopt
```

Missing `a`,`6`,`mm`.

I need to modify the function so that the duplicate removal will not consider strings with len <=2 or any kind of integer instead, these values should remain as they are.

```
def uniqueList(row):
    words = str(row).split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in unique.lower() :
            unique = unique + " " + w

return unique

df["Correction_Value"] = df["Correction_Value"].apply(uniqueList)
```

Comment: Explain the logic of 'moving' from  sample1 to sample2

Comment: According to your logic `mm,` , will still be missing since it's not `< 2`

Comment: @Superbman yes, you're right, I have edited the question, however, there's no logic in the function, that is actually what I'm looking for.

Comment: @balderman I'm removing duplicates from the first example but as you can see in the final sample, is removing 'mm', '6' and 'a' as are found as duplicates. I need to create an exception in my function for integers and words with length less or equal to 2 keeping them in the sentence in the same time

Comment: @Isa, if you split on a space, `mm` is going to be `mm,` - 3 letters which is still removed from your resulting string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. Not the best code, but it get's the job done - it passes the test.

```py
def uniqueList(row):
    words = str(row).split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        
        try:
            int(w)
            unique = unique + " " + w
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        if 'mm' in w:
            unique = unique + " " + w
            continue

        if (w.lower() not in unique.lower()) or (len(w) <= 2):
            unique = unique + " " + w

    return unique

df["Correction_Value"] = df["Correction_Value"].apply(uniqueList)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try to remove duplicates on rows but I need to have strings with length <= 2 and integer.

The code below does that (**Note** that `mm` != `mm,`)

```
def rem_dups(value: str) -> str:
    def _is_int(x):
        try:
            int(x)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    result = []
    seen = set()
    words = value.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) <= 2 or _is_int(word):
            result.append(word)
        else:
            if word.lower() not in seen and word.upper() not in seen:
                result.append(word)
                seen.add(word)
    return ' '.join(result)


_value = 'AIR OPTIX Air Optix plus HydraGlyde Lenti a Contatto Mensili, 6 Lenti, BC a 6 mm, DIA 14.2 mm, -0.75 Diopt'
print(rem_dups(_value))
```

output

```
AIR OPTIX plus HydraGlyde Lenti a Contatto Mensili, 6 Lenti, BC a 6 mm, DIA 14.2 -0.75 Diopt
```